Outlook emails cleared but still get error "The server response was: 5.2.2 Mailbox full"?
I have an outlook email where the emails have been cleared from deleted and recoverable items.
The folders are all empty and its been about 2-3 days , but still the error comes and says "mailbox full".
Is there anything I am missing with this and is there a way that i can make the process register that emails are empty a bit quicker ?
Why would this still happen if the email folders are empty ?
